# ASP.NET Core 2.1 bug: can`t use class Controller, property ViewData

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core-2.1

I've updated my VS 2017 to newer version, and now projects on ASP.NET Core 2.1 are available to me. But there is very strange bug in C# controller code:

[image]

If you know hot to solve that problem, please, let me know.

Comment: check your assemblies references for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.dll` also does this compile and run?

Comment: I connected namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures, but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

First clean your solution by right click on solution and then built it if it still then You need to install dependencies from new get packages....this is just because of not find dependencies
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Tool
......................................SqlServer
......................................Design
Or other  i forgot check if this correct it